# Question that appears not to be from me in list of deleted questions

Tags: support, deleted-questions, post-ban, reputation-history

I am trying to tidy up my account, while looking my history of questions I noticed one I do not recall asking, it has been a long time since I can remember dealing with python. It was asked as showing in the image on 22Sep/20

Unlike all my other questions there is no hyperlink against it, so I can not see the text of the question.  It's got a -18 downvote/reputation against it, that is the thing I think I would remember.  It's not a question age related issue because there are questions further down the list that I can access

Fair enough, if I asked it, I want to deal with it, but since I can not see the text, there is currently nothing I can do about.

Can anybody explain to me how:

1. How can I access it?
2. Why is there is no hyperlink?

> [image]

Comment: I have checked my ' recently deleted answers', but that only goes back 60 days, this item has been collecting dust for the last 75 days.  

I am just worried that the -18 reputation code counts against me

Comment: @Dave it doesn't. It just means you got +18 reputation for that answer and after it was deleted, you lost it. It's not a "penalty" but balancing out to a net zero for the question. Rep is (mostly) based on all active posts, so if a post is deleted, you don't get positive or negative rep from it. There are some exceptions, IIRC - something like if the post was up for X amount of days, you do retain the rep from it. I can't find the rules for this right now to verify.

Comment: @VLAZ Found it! https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/

Comment: Oh it was A score of 3 or greater or

Visible on the site for at least 60 days

Comment: @ppwater thanks for your effort in finding this! I tried searching MSO, MSE and google but hit nothing. Admittedly, I didn't put much effort in trying all search variations. So, judging from the 18 rep, the score was most likely +2/-1 which would be why the rep was lost.

Comment: @VLAZ, thank you for clearing that point, up. I got barred.
 I am rather interested in doing something about it. All I saw was -18 against what appear to be against a deleted question that I owned, hence number one target for some action

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That question *was* asked by you, back on March 16, 2016, and it can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031579/max-function-processing-off-lists-an-expected-resultpython-newbie

It had a net score of 1 (+2/-1), which would net you 18 reputation (2 × 10 for upvotes, minus 2 for a downvote, equals 18).

You deleted it 3 months ago. Deleted posts no longer count towards your reputation (because they are not adding value to the site), so your reputation was adjusted automatically by removing the 18 points that you had netted from that question.

The reason it isn't a hyperlink is because it's no longer visible to you from your profile, since it was deleted more than 60 days ago.

---

In related news, you have 21 deleted questions (including that one) with a score of <= 0:

- [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/63694442)
- [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/63636032)
- [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/62766038)
- [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/61857436)
- [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/61316460)
- [6](//stackoverflow.com/q/57677195)
- [7](//stackoverflow.com/q/56953628)
- [8](//stackoverflow.com/q/53467293)
- [9](//stackoverflow.com/q/51823210)
- [10](//stackoverflow.com/q/51734547)
- [11](//stackoverflow.com/q/50982359)
- [12](//stackoverflow.com/q/45470534)
- [13](//stackoverflow.com/q/44323157)
- [14](//stackoverflow.com/q/44093624)
- [15](//stackoverflow.com/q/43545809)
- [16](//stackoverflow.com/q/40449216)
- [17](//stackoverflow.com/q/36269775)
- [18](//stackoverflow.com/q/31908652)
- [19](//stackoverflow.com/q/31145354)
- [20](//stackoverflow.com/q/31089196)
- [21](//stackoverflow.com/q/27201332)

The [question ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) is a *total* quality score, so it takes into account both deleted and undeleted posts. Based on your wording in the question ("I am trying to tidy up my account…"), it sounds like you might be trying to go through and delete old questions. Please note that, as explained in the linked Help Center article, **simply deleting your old questions doesn't help to lift the question ban**. You need to *improve* those questions, rather than deleting them. I've provided you with the links above, so you can decide which of them are candidates for improvement.

Comment: I was some curious what would happen if I undeleted some my previous naff questions, I had original deleted them because they were adding no value, some of them are over 4 years old etc.

The community deamon process noticed them and deleted again.  I guess I am stuck with them as a millstone, because its a bit hard to add anything to an issue that is either out of date or is no longer the accepted wisdom for resolving an issue.